# UILabel with attributed number formatted text inserts `-character

Tags: objective-c, ios7, nsnumberformatter

I'm using a UILabel with a currency which I got through

```
    NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [NSNumberFormatter new];
    [[NSThread currentThread] threadDictionary][numberFormatterKey] = numberFormatter;
    [numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
    numberFormatter.currencyCode = @"EUR";
```

My resulting string looks good, e.g. `-4.098,83 €` when I log it. But my label displays `` -4.098,83`€ ``- so there's an additional character before the currency. Why is this and how can I avoid it?

Comment: the number formatting depends on the locale you are using. basically the system's local is used for the formatter unless you re-define it explicitly.

Comment: my system local is german which doesn't include that sign... that's why I'm confused